# AHK How to switch Ctrl and Shift keys

Tags: keyboard, switch-statement, autohotkey, shift, ctrl

I would like to switch Left Shift and Ctrl key, so whenever I press Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> I get
Ctrl P instead. But also I will like that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> (No <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>). I mean just call the Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys switch when I press the Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> in combination with letters and numbers, but not when I press it with any other modifiers.

I have tried this so far

```
~LShift::~LCtrl
```

It do the trick, but, with this scritpt whenever I press <kbd>Lshift</kbd> I get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how your script should look if you want to switch shift and Ctrl completely.

```
$*Lshift::Send {LControl Down}
$*Lshift Up::Send {LControl Up}

$*LControl::Send {Lshift Down}
$*LControl Up::Send {Lshift Up}
```

Your question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624933/windows-going-crazy-after-typing-romanian-characters-using-a-romanian-programmer) where you will find the explanation why this works.

Comment: You missed a little space at `LshiftUp` ;)