# Windows going crazy after typing Romanian characters using a Romanian Programmers layout while remapping Alt/Ctrl/Win with Autohotkey

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey

I've remapped some keys using Autohotkey, like this:

```
LWin::LAlt

LCtrl::LWin

LAlt::LCtrl
```

I'm using Windows 7 with the Romanian (Programmers) keyboard layout. If I want to type ă I hit RAlt + a, for example. It's called "Programmers" because it's a reqular US QWERTY layout with extras activated by RAlt.

However, if I run my Autohotkey script AND then I send a RAlt + a/s/t/i, the system goes bonkers. Even if I close Autohotkey it still behaves like that. I have to log off/reboot or hit magic key sequence to fix it (I still haven't figured out what sequence).

What I'm guessing happens is that Alt somehow gets stuck and every key I press is mixed up with Alt. Pressing Esc switches Windows, pressing F while in an application opens the File menu, etc.

Is this an Autohotkey bug or am I doing something wrong?

I've used SharpKeys in the past for this but due to some requirements - shared computer - I need something per user and that preferably can be turned off. Autohotkey would have been perfect for this.

Thank you.

Late edit - the solution was what 576i (first section + key mappings to replace the previous keyboard mapping I was using - I gave up Romanian Programmers)

```
; Remap Ctrl to Win, Win to Alt, Alt to Ctrl - credit to 579i
$*LWin::Send {LAlt Down} 
$*LWin Up::Send {LAlt Up}

$*LCtrl::Send {LWin Down}
$*LCtrl Up::Send {LWin Up}

$*LAlt::Send {LControl Down}
$*LAlt Up::Send {LControl Up}

; Keyboard mappings for Romanian letters
; First of all - GTK Windows are special and need special treatment
#IfWinActive, ahk_class gdkWindowToplevel
    >!a::SendInput {Control Down}{Shift Down}u0103{Control Up}{Shift Up}
    >!+a::SendInput {Control Down}{Shift Down}u0102{Control Up}{Shift Up}
    >!q::SendInput {Control Down}{Shift Down}u00E2{Control Up}{Shift Up}
    >!+q::SendInput {Control Down}{Shift Down}u00C2{Control Up}{Shift Up}
    >!i::SendInput {Control Down}{Shift Down}u00EE{Control Up}{Shift Up}
    >!+i::SendInput {Control Down}{Shift Down}u00CE{Control Up}{Shift Up}
    >!s::SendInput {Control Down}{Shift Down}u0219{Control Up}{Shift Up}
    >!+s::SendInput {Control Down}{Shift Down}u0218{Control Up}{Shift Up}
    >!t::SendInput {Control Down}{Shift Down}u021B{Control Up}{Shift Up}
    >!+t::SendInput {Control Down}{Shift Down}u021A{Control Up}{Shift Up}
; Then regular windows
#IfWinActive
    >!a::Send ă
    >!+a::Send Ă
    >!q::Send â
    >!+q::Send Â
    >!i::Send î
    >!+i::Send Î
    >!s::Send ș
    >!+s::Send Ș
    >!t::Send ț
    >!+t::Send Ț
```

[Edited to include the GTK fix; this still doesn't work for console Windows and there are some weird glitches when pasting, sometimes Ctrl is interpreted as Alt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your right Alt key is an Alt-Gr key it will be
intepreted as LControl & RAlt which triggers your script.

Also it looks like you got an endless loop there.

Look at this example, this should work better for you.

The **$** before hotkeys prevents that the key you
"Send" triggers the next hotkey. The ***** makes sure
the key also works when pressed with other keys.

```
$*LWin::Send {LAlt Down}
$*LWin Up::Send {LAlt Up}

$*LCtrl::Send {LWin Down}
$*LCtrl Up::Send {LWin Up}

$*LAlt::Send {LControl Down}
$*LAlt Up::Send {LControl Up}
```

This remapping might still kill your Alt-Gr key if
your keyboard drivers sends "LControl & RAlt" internally.

You can fix this creating a special hotkey either for Alt-Gr
or - if the romanian keyboard has only a few Alt-Gr combinations,
define those as hotkeys.

Example from the Autohotkey help file *Hotkey* page:

```
<^>!m::MsgBox You pressed AltGr+m.
<^<!m::MsgBox You pressed LeftControl+LeftAlt+m.
```

Comment: I get this:    "A5  138   u 0.11 RAlt" from Key history. So it should be RAlt, however using >!s or RAlt & s to send ş doesn't work, it just presses Alt and I get the menu thingie again :|

Comment: Hint: Make sure you write a script without the lCtlr and lAlt mapping before you use the keyboard history to look uo what happens if you press ş

Comment: Autohotkey really isn't the best development environment - the edit/reload/close/test cycle isn't that great. I did manage to make it work, thanks for the great post & comments :)