# Remapping Ctrl using AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

Both my Control keys are broken on my Keyboard. In the meantime while I get a replacement, I've been trying to remap it to different keys. I watched a few youtube videos and scoured the web and this is the code I came up with to remap Ctrl to my tilde key (~/`) using AutoHotKey.

```
LCtrl::`
```

I am very, very, very bad at coding so I was wondering if anyone could tell me what I did wrong on this script.

Comment: are you not wondering why your command does not contain a `~`?

Comment: this is similar ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622429/ahk-how-to-switch-ctrl-and-shift-keys

Answer (score 0):

You switched them up.

If your control keys are broken, and you want tilde to act as your temporary left control, this should work:

```
`::LCtrl ; Remap tilde to LCtrl
```